# What is the backend language of Automation Anywhere? Where and how can we view the line by line scripts for the bots?

Tags: automationanywhere

Is it possible to see the backend scripts for the automation anywhere ".atmx" files? or other files it associates the bots with? I tried with notepad but its all gibberish, (maybe it's encrypted). Any particular editor this can work?

If different file than .atmx what is it? which directory?

What language is it using to do the RPA instructions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client application is using .NET (right now) and you cannot open .atmx files because they are indeed encrypted.

Comment: Do you have maybe any idea if there is a possibility of decrypting Mbots ?

Comment: @Piot If you unzip the .mbot files you will find logic files that are basically .atmx files, also encrypted. You will also find the .dll files if there were any.